# Full Calendar event to bootstrap modal dialog not work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am used this [fullcalendar-scheduler](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-scheduler/releases)  I am try to added Modal Popup dialog box for that events,Its not working for me, please help me to fix that issue.

event function

```
eventClick:  function(event, jsEvent, view) {
            $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
            $('#modalBody').html(event.description);
            $('#eventUrl').attr('href',event.url);
            $('#calendarModal').modal();
        },
```

This is my code

```
 <script>

    $(function() { // document ready

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            now: '2017-12',
            editable: true, // enable draggable events
              height: 'auto',
            header: {
                left: 'today prev,next',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'timelineMonth,timelineYear'
            },
            defaultView: 'timelineThreeDays',
               navLinks: true,
              resourceAreaWidth: '15%',
            views: {
                timelineThreeDays: {
                    type: 'timeline',
                    duration: { days: 31}
                }
            },
            resourceLabelText: 'Single Rooms (8)',

            resources: [
                { id: 'a', title: 'Room # 1' },
                { id: 'b', title: 'Room # 2', eventColor: 'green' },
                { id: 'c', title: 'Room # 3', eventColor: 'orange' },
                { id: 'd', title: 'Room # 4', children: [

                ] },
                { id: 'e', title: 'Room # 5' },
                { id: 'f', title: 'Room # 6', eventColor: 'red' },
                { id: 'g', title: 'Room # 7', eventColor: 'orange'  },
                { id: 'h', title: 'Room # 8',eventColor: 'green'  },

            ],
            events: [

                // normal events...
                { id: '1', resourceId: 'a', start: '2017-12-01', end: '2017-12-07', title: 'Mahesh' },
                { id: '2', resourceId: 'b', start: '2017-12-12', end: '2017-12-15', title: 'Anushka' },
                { id: '3', resourceId: 'c', start: '2017-12-11', end: '2017-12-15', title: 'Ramesh' },
                { id: '4', resourceId: 'd', start: '2017-12-11', end: '2017-12-19', title: 'Susena' },
                { id: '5', resourceId: 'e', start: '2017-12-15', end: '2017-12-28', title: 'Lahiru' },
                { id: '6', resourceId: 'f', start: '2017-12-01', end: '2017-12-10', title: 'Chamath' },
                { id: '7', resourceId: 'g', start: '2017-12-10', end: '2017-12-11', title: 'Channa' },
                { id: '8', resourceId: 'h', start: '2017-12-09', end: '2017-12-14', title: 'Ganesh' }
            ],

eventClick:  function(event, jsEvent, view) {
            $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
            $('#modalBody').html(event.description);
            $('#eventUrl').attr('href',event.url);
            $('#calendarModal').modal();
        },
        });
    });

</script>
```

**Modal**

```
<div id="calendarModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span> <span class="sr-only">close</span></button>
            <h4 id="modalTitle" class="modal-title"></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body"> </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
    <!-- Modal -->
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG ,It's work for now , Simply is my mistake ,

**before** >>  Im used  `bootstrap.js`

now Im replaced `bootstrap.min.js`

now its working :)

Comment: are you sure that's the issue? There should be no functional difference between those two files. One is just a compressed version of the other. The only reason it could cause a change is a) the files are actually copies of different versions of Bootstrap or b) your web page had a `<script` reference already which expected the .min.js and you hadn't included that in your deployment. Was it related to one of those issues? Otherwise I can't see how it would make any difference.

Comment: I know it worked for you, but I was asking _why_. I gave two possible reasons. Was it one of those reasons? Or something else? It might be useful for future readers to understand what the underlying issue was.

Comment: understood, it's my mistake ,I was added` bootstrap.js` for calendar.html  but my home page are  always used `bootstrap.min.js`, after I removed   bootstrap.js` and re added   `bootstrap.min.js` for calendar.html

Answer (score 0):

This happens due any DOM element inside of a Modal element (Bootstrap [Modals](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/)) will be hidden thus Calendar object won't be rendered. A workaround for this is to init the calendar after click event on the toggler.

```
# HTML
<button id="toggler" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_calendar"></button>

<div id="modal_calendar" class="modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="calendar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


# Script
<script>
    (function($){

        $('#toggler').on('click', function(){
           $('.calendar').fullCalendar();
        })

    })(jQuery)
</script>
```